# Share Web through another port

Tags: sharing, webserver, network

I have a webserver running on a MBA at port 4431 and I want to access through my local network.

But web sharing uses port 80 by default and I can't access to my_mba_ip:4431

Can I add ports to web sharing? I found this old, old post ([Changing the OS X Web Server Port](http://homepage.mac.com/car1son/change_apache_port.html)) where seems the solution to my problem, but I don't know how to do that in Lion :(

Answer (score 1):

The location of the httpd.conf in lion is the following:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And you will search for the line to change that has the following:

```
Listen 80
```

The rest of that document you linked should work.

I would however recommend using MAMP for much better control of apache and mysql.

[MAMP](http://mamp.info/)